# ResearchKit stepResult for a TextChoiceQuestion

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

I'm using ResearchKit's `stepResultForStepIdentifier` method successfully for other question types, but can't find correct syntax to pre-populate the results for a TextChoiceQuestion.

Below is an unsuccessful attempt at setting the result for the sample TextChoice question in ORKCatalog. Any advice on correct approach?

```
func stepResultForStepIdentifier(stepIdentifier: String) -> ORKStepResult? {

    var stepResults = [ORKQuestionResult]()

    if stepIdentifier == "TextChoiceQuestionStep" {

        var questionDefault = ORKChoiceQuestionResult(identifier: stepIdentifier)

        questionDefault.choiceAnswers?.append("choice_2")

        stepResults.append(questionDefault)

    }

    var defaults = ORKStepResult(stepIdentifier: stepIdentifier, results: stepResults)

    return defaults
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `choiceAnswers` array `nil`? When you do `questionDefault.choiceAnswers?.append`, `choiceAnswers` might be `nil`, so this might do nothing.

Instead do `questionDefault.choiceAnswers = ["choice_2"]`

Comment: Thanks. That works. I added a check for whether the array is nil   -  `if questionDefault.choiceAnswers == nil {
        questionDefault.choiceAnswers = ["choice_2"]
    } else {
        questionDefault.choiceAnswers?.append("choice_2")
    }`